# Story and versus mode

Tags: ps4, injustice-gods-among-us

I got injustice ultimate edition the other day on the PSN. The game finished downloading fine. When I booted it up I was met with a message saying that not all the characters and content had finished downloading but I was still able to play single fight mode. After a few fights all the characters and the STAR labs opened up but, the other 2 modes were still locked.

Now my internet is not fast so is it just a matter of me having to wait for some invisible download to finish to get the other content? If so does the game itself have to be running for this to take place?

Comment: Can you specify which [game modes](http://www.ign.com/wikis/injustice-gods-among-us/Game_Modes) you are specifically unable to access?  [This reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2o9qm0/psn_plus_free_game_injustice_story_mode_is_locked/) mentions how you can check that the game is fully downloaded.  [This post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/734631-injustice-gods-among-us-ultimate-edition/68507474) also look familiar with your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game has installed enough to be playable, but is not completely installed yet.  You can check that a game has been fully installed by following the steps mentioned [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2o9qm0/psn_plus_free_game_injustice_story_mode_is_locked/).

1. Go to game icon
2. Click options
3. Then information

   - It tells you how much has finished downloading

On the PS4, this feature is called [PlayGo](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/PlayGo).  That article states:

> PlayGo allows immediate start of **supported games**, with only the need of the first chunk of game data

However, I am unable to find a list of supported games for this feature.